# Compare uploaded and downloaded files in Jsch Java

Tags: java, file, compare, sftp, jsch

I am using the SFTP Jsch library to upload a file to a remote machine via the first user. After that, I log in via another user and check that file is uploaded, and then download it. My task is to compare the downloaded file vs the uploaded file. Also, for a few minutes, I need to observe the directory until no new files have arrived.

I am able to upload the file as well as download the file. But I didn't find any method with which I can compare the uploaded and downloaded file. I mean via time data or something like that.

Any help or tip would be greatly appreciated.

```
package lio.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import com.maverick.sftp.SftpFile;
import com.maverick.sftp.SftpStatusException;
import com.maverick.ssh.SshException;


public class lio_02_testing
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(lio_02_testing.class);

private static final int portSFTP = 1000;
private static String host = "some_ip";
private static String unameUpload = "uploading_ID";
private static String unameDownload = "Downloading_ID";
private static String password = "skyisblue";
private static String sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\lio\\Downloads\\";
private static String fileName = "LIO00695_testFile.txt";
private static String downloadFilePath = "C:\\Users\\lio\\Downloads\\testing";
private static String desFilePath = "/remotemachine/";
public static String remoteFileDownload= "";

@Test(description = "Testing upload and download")
public static void testing() throws InstallationException, IOException, JSchException, SftpException, SshException
{

    log.info("Starting sending file via SFTP.");
    uplaodFile();
    downloadFile(); 
    contentFileCompare(fileName, remoteFileDownload);
    
}
public static void uploadFile()
{
   JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try
    {

        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(unameUpload, host, portSFTP);
        jschSession.setPassword(password);
        jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");    
        jschSession.connect();
        Channel channel = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        String fileNameUpload = fileName;
        sftpChannel.put(sourcePath + fileName, desFilePath);
        sftpChannel.exit();
        jschSession.disconnect();
    }

    catch (JSchException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }

 public static void downloadFile()
 {
 // Second step is login via another user and try to download that file which is send.
    JSch jsch_amps = new JSch();
    try
    {

        Session jschSession = jsch_amps.getSession(unameDownload, host, portSFTP);
        jschSession.setPassword(password);
        jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jschSession.connect();
        Channel channel = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        sftpChannel.cd(receiverPathDirSFTP);
        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls("*.txt");
        String regex = ".*?LIO[0-9]{7}[5-9]{1}.*";
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list)
        {
            System.out.println("Entering in the for loop");
            if (entry.getFilename().matches(regex))
            {
                remoteFileDownload = entry.getFilename();
                sftpChannel.get(remoteFileDownload , downloadFilePath);

            }

        }

        sftpChannel.exit();
        jschSession.disconnect();
    }

    catch (JSchException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
   //compare the contents
    public static void contentFileCompare(File upload, File download) throws IOException
{
    boolean compare1and2 = FileUtils.contentEquals(upload, download);
}
}
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Can you show via code?. I tried to do so but failed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I updated. I create the function where i can compare the contents, but the problem i am getting is "The method contentFileCompare(File, File) in the type uploadDownloadTest is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is giving the error. because once the file is uploaded. its name is changed. e.g from LIO00695_testFile.txt to LIOFROM_LIO00695_testFile.txt.     the error is 'LIO00695_testFile.txt' does not exists  .   i used   Assert.assertEquals(FileUtils.readLines(new File(fileName)), FileUtils.readLines(new File(remoteFileDownload)), "Contents are not equal");
.